# gitlab-ce on pre-installed nginx server on centos 8 gives 502 error

Tags: nginx, centos8, gitlab-ce

I am getting the ***502 Whoops, GitLab is taking too much time to respond*** error on my fresh Manual installation of Gitlab-ce 13.2.4 on CENTOS 8 (nginx/1.16.1).

I downloaded the rpm [gitlab-ce-13.2.4-ce.0.el8.x86_64.rpm](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/el/8/gitlab-ce-13.2.4-ce.0.el8.x86_64.rpm)

- `dnf -y install policycoreutils-python-utils`
- `rpm -Uvh gitlab-ce-13.2.4-ce.0.el8.x86_64.rpm`
- `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb >> external_url "https://git.mydomain.com"`
- `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb >> nginx['enable'] = false`
- `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb >> web_server['external_users'] = ['nginx']`
- `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb >> gitlab_rails['trusted_proxies'] = [ '172.16.1.0/24', '192.168.10.0/24']`
- `/etc/nginx/conf.d/git.mydomain.com.conf >> https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/raw/master/lib/support/nginx/gitlab-ssl`
- `systemctl restart nginx`
- `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

My [git.mydomain.com.conf](https://gitlab.com/ratan.thapa/gitlab-nginx-conf/-/raw/master/git.mydomain.com.conf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My selinux was blocking the url to run. probably the gitlab directory access.
I run `setenforce 0` and it worked (which is not a good practice though).

EDIT: chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/opt/gitlab/